# Resize google map in jQuery toggle div - display issue

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, toggle

I have a small div displaying a google map. On click of button i have map div panel expanding bigger - simple jQuery toggle.

This works fine but the map is not displaying correctly once toggled to larger size. I'm using

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function()
```

and

```
var currCenter = map.getCenter();
```

to allow for the container resize and re-centering of map but for some reason it's not working.

It's creating the issue of grey blocks and not centering.

[image: map]

Here's the google maps code i'm using:

```
    function initMap() {
        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          zoom: 8,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
        });

        //Get current center
        var currCenter = map.getCenter();

        //Use event listener for resize on window
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
        //Set Center
        map.setCenter(getCen);
    });
```

Here's JSFiddle link to see what i've got so far: https://jsfiddle.net/9ejvmn4q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me if I trigger the resize event once the `.toggleClass` function has run (the requirement is that it be triggered once the div has been resized, so if there is any animation or asynchronous delay, you may need to account for that).

Note also, that for the `map` `resize` and `setCenter` to work, the `map` and `currCenter` variables need to be in the correct scope.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.map-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.map').toggleClass('fullsize');
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(currCenter);
    });
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vtgnuyut/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.map-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.map').toggleClass('fullsize');
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(currCenter);
  });
});
```

```css
.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#content {
  width: 560px;
}
.map-section {} .map {
  width: 140px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
}
.map.fullsize {
  width: 100%;
}
.map-toggle {} .student-results-main {
  float: left;
  width: 390px;
  background: #ddd;
  min-height: 300px;
}
.student-results-sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 140px;
  background: #eee;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<script>
  var currCenter;
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    });

    //Get current center
    currCenter = map.getCenter();

    //Use event listener for resize on window
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
      //Set Center
      map.setCenter(currCenter);
    });
  }
</script>

<div id="content">
  <div class="map-section">
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="student-results-main"></div>

  <div class="student-results-sidebar">
    <button class="map-toggle">toggle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```